# Кнопка для бота telebot

Tags: python, telebot

Я нигде не могу найти что-то подобное  [image]

Мне нужно, чтобы бот отправлял 2 кнопки (таких же) с текстом "Привет". Подскажите, как это сделать (библеотека TeleBot)

Answer (score 0):

```py
from telebot import types

...

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def inline_key(a):
    if a.text == "Ку":
        mainmenu = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        key1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Привет', callback_data='but1')
        key2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Привет', callback_data='but2')
        mainmenu.add(key1, key2)
        bot.send_message(a.chat.id, 'Дарова', reply_markup=mainmenu)

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_inline(call):
    if call.data == "but1":
        bot.edit_message_text('Ты нажал на кнопку 1', call.message.chat.id, call.message.message_id)
    elif call.data == "but2":
        bot.edit_message_text('Ты нажал на кнопку 2', call.message.chat.id, call.message.message_id)

bot.polling()
```

Пишем сообщение `ку`, бот выводит нам меню с двумя кнопками <kbd>привет</kbd>. Пробуйте